# What is the correct place to put commands to be executed by capistrano?

Tags: shell, capistrano

I am trying to get `capistrano` to use `chruby` but I keep getting the error `bundle stderr: /bin/sh: 1: chruby: not found`

I need to run `source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh` so that the shell can find the command chruby.

I have gone through [this](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/), and understand interactive/non-interactive shells, login/non-login shells. Logically, I did not want to use `pty: true` so I tried to use `$BASH_ENV` but still same error. Also, I realized no one is doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I use `rbenv` on Ubuntu 14.04, but I imagine your setup is probably similar. My solution is to put the rbenv shell initialization logic at the very top of my deploy user's `.bashrc`, like this:

```
if [ -d $HOME/.rbenv ]; then
  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# ... snip
```

The important thing to notice is that the rbenv code will be executed *even for non-interactive shells*, because it is placed before the interactive check.

So you could probably do the same thing, where you put the chruby script at the top:

```
source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

I have not used chruby, so take this with a grain of salt.